# java.util.stream.Collectors with EnumSet Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, enumset

I'm trying to use in place of bitmask below is the code

```
public static Set<Amenities> fromBitFlags(int bitFlag) {
    return ALL_OPTS.stream().filter(a -> (a.ameityId & bitFlag) > 0).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

I would like to return EnumSet instead of a plain set(dont want to loose out on EnumSet's usefulness just because of casting).

Need some directions on how to create a Custom Collector to collect EnumSet.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You may use [`toCollection(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```
return ALL_OPTS.stream().filter(a -> (a.ameityId & bitFlag) > 0)
               .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> EnumSet.noneOf(Amenities.class)));
```

The `toCollection` method receives a lambda which should create an empty collection to store the result. Here we create empty `EnumSet` using `EnumSet.noneOf` call. Note that for `EnumSet` you must always specify (implicitly or explicitly) which enum is this set for.

Comment: Thanks a lot, would be really helpful if you could explain this lambda in brief `() -> EnumSet.noneOf(Amenities.class)` , how this creates a Supplier that can automatically call `EnumSet.add()`

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar, added some explanation. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Mind the alternative of `EnumSet<Amenities> s=EnumSet.copyOf(ALL_OPTS); s.removeIf(a -> (a.ameityId & bitFlag) <= 0);`…

Comment: @Holger that's a bad alternative, as it might throw an unnecessary  `IllegalArgumentException` if the Collection ALL_OPTS is empty and not an instance of `EnumSet`.

Comment: @qutax the naming style suggests that `ALL_OPTS` is a constant containing all options, with a predictable non-empty content. The OP’s concerns about losing EnumSet's usefulness also suggest that `ALL_OPTS` is an `EnumSet` in the first place. Of course, it would be easy to fix if that’s not the case.

Comment: If ALL_OPTS is an `EnumSet`, chances are high that its not actually a constant, as `JumboEnumSet` and `RegularEnumSet` are both mutable and I don't think that the OP implemented an unmodifiable implementation of `EnumSet`. And yes, for this special case it is likely that ALL_OPTS is not empty (even though depending on the actual case ALL_OPTS could be none opts at all, I guess). But as people often copy-and-paste code found on SO, even if it doesn't match their case 100%, I felt the need to point out the chance of producing an Exception when using your — in my opinion bad — alternative.

Comment: @qutax if `ALL_OPTS` is an `EnumSet`, it doesn’t matter whether it is empty, as `EnumSet.copyOf(ALL_OPTS)` will always work. In fact, I’d consider the case that `ALL_OPTS` is empty worth producing an exception, rather than proceeding with an empty result set.

Comment: @Holger's alternative is fine. It's highly unlikely that `ALL_OPTS` is an empty non-`EnumSet`. If it is, that's probably a bug, and I *want* to get an exception. Anyway, in most cases you probably don't need `ALL_OPTS` anyway (premature optimization?) and you can replace `EnumSet.copyOf(ALL_OPTS)` by `EnumSet.allOf(Amenities.class)`.