# what is a proper "supplier" for a "stream.collector" of EnumSet?

Tags: java, java-stream, collect, supplier

The following code does not compile:

```
    HashSet<Integer> nlsCandidates;         // added here to help read the stream coding below
    EnumSet<ScConstraint>[] rowConstraints; // added here to help read the stream coding below
    EnumSet<ScConstraint> tbd = nlsCandidates.stream()
        .flatMap(p -> rowConstraints[10*k + p].stream())
        .filter(cstr -> !s.contains(cstr.RC))
        .collect(EnumSet.noneOf(ScConstraint.class), (c, cstr) -> c.add(cstr), EnumSet::addAll);
```

This is the error message:

```
no suitable method found for collect(EnumSet<ScConstraint>,(c,cstr)->[...]cstr),EnumSet::addAll)
        .collect(EnumSet.noneOf(ScConstraint.class), (c, cstr) -> c.add(cstr), EnumSet::addAll);
        ^
method Stream.<R#1>collect(Supplier<R#1>,BiConsumer<R#1,? super ScConstraint>,BiConsumer<R#1,R#1>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) R#1
    (argument mismatch; no instance(s) of type variable(s) E exist so that EnumSet<E> conforms to Supplier<R#1>))

method Stream.<R#2,A>collect(Collector<? super ScConstraint,A,R#2>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) R#2,A
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))

where R#1,T,E,R#2,A are type-variables:
R#1 extends Object declared in method <R#1>collect(Supplier<R#1>,BiConsumer<R#1,? super T>,BiConsumer<R#1,R#1>)
T extends Object declared in interface Stream
E extends Enum<E> declared in method <E>noneOf(Class<E>)
R#2 extends Object declared in method <R#2,A>collect(Collector<? super T,A,R#2>)
A extends Object declared in method <R#2,A>collect(Collector<? super T,A,R#2>)
```

I need the `Supplier` to return an empty EnumSet. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does this help: [java.util.stream.Collectors with EnumSet Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178294/java-util-stream-collectors-with-enumset-stream)?

Comment: How about `() -> EnumSet.noneOf(ScConstraint.class)`?

Comment: @li: no, I get the following runtime error:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: j$.util.stream.Stream$VivifiedWrapper cannot be cast to java.util.stream.Stream
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:280)

Comment: @Maurice: no, same run time error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument of the tree-args flavor of [`Stream.collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) is of type [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html). It's a *function* which is meant to provide a mutable object, that would be used to accumulate stream elements and would be returned as the result of the stream execution.

As it was [mentioned by @MauricePerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74299142/what-is-a-proper-supplier-for-a-stream-collector-of-enumset#comment131172781_74299142) in the comments, you've provided a value, i.e. an `EnumSet` itself, not a `Supplier` of an `EnumSet`. Therefore, you're getting a compilation error due to the mismatch of type of the argument and expected type.

The correct code can be written like this:

```
EnumSet<ScConstraint> tbd = nlsCandidates.stream()
    .flatMap(p -> rowConstraints[10 * k + p].stream())
    .filter(cstr -> !s.contains(cstr.RC))
    .collect(
        () -> EnumSet.noneOf(ScConstraint.class),
        Set::add,
        Set::addAll
    );
```

Alternatively, you can make use of the [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) version expecting an instance of `Collector` as an argument. And as a Collector, you can provide [`toCollection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection(java.util.function.Supplier)) (*credits to @Holger*):

```
EnumSet<ScConstraint> tbd = nlsCandidates.stream()
    .flatMap(p -> rowConstraints[10 * k + p].stream())
    .filter(cstr -> !s.contains(cstr.RC))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(
        () -> EnumSet.noneOf(ScConstraint.class)
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. And the compilation error is fixed.